# Adding Command line arguments in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to programming and python and am having trouble understanding some code I found for a webscraper that pulls closed captions from youtube videos. I noticed that it passes the argument "start_url" into the "YoutubeSubtitleScraper" function. start_url is defined just above that as index position 1 of the sys.argv. Am I right in my interpretation that the "start_url" is defined as equal to the index position 1 command line argument passed to the script? if so then how do you make the desired url command line argument index position 1?

```html
import sys
import time
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class YoutubeSubtitlesScraper:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

        self.driver.get(start_url)
        self.display_all_videos()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.driver.close()

    def display_all_videos(self):
        """Clicks on "Load More" button to display all users videos."""
        while True:
            try:
                element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "yt-uix-load-more")))
                element.click()
            except TimeoutException:
                break

    def subtitles(self):
        """Visits video's page, enables 'CC' to scrape the subtitles and generates filename, link and the subtitles content."""
        videos = [(video.text, video.get_attribute("href"))
                  for video in self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yt-uix-tile-link")]

        for filename, link in videos:
            self.driver.get(link)
            self.enable_subtitles()

            link = self.get_subtitles_link()
            yield filename, link, self.scrape_subtitles(link) if link else "No Closed Caption"

    def enable_subtitles(self):
        """Clicks on CC(Closed Caption) button in YouTube video."""
        show_subtitles_button = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ytp-subtitles-button")))
        show_subtitles_button.click()

    def get_subtitles_link(self):
        """Finds string in performance timings that contains the substring 'srv3' which is the subtitles link."""
        time.sleep(1)
        timings = self.driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries();")

        for timing in timings:
            for value in timing.values():
                if "srv3" in str(value):
                    return value
        return ""

    def scrape_subtitles(self, subtitle_link):
        """HTML parses subtitles."""
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(subtitle_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
        return soup.get_text(strip=True)


def create_file(filename, link, subtitles):
    """Creates file for the subtitle."""
    title = "".join([c for c in filename if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c == ' ']).rstrip()

    with open(title + '.txt', 'w') as subtitles_file:
        subtitles_file.write('LINK: ' + link + '\n')
        subtitles_file.write(subtitles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_url = sys.argv[1]

    with YoutubeSubtitlesScraper(start_url) as scraper:
        for filename, link, content in scraper.subtitles():
            try:
                create_file(filename, link, content)
            except:
                print("Can't create file for: " + filename + " : " + link)
```

I printed the entire sys.argv and it returns:

['/Users/Justin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', '/Users/Justin/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-46dfc313-57c1-4c81-97ab-a55b6f45acf5.json']

so the code above is currently pulling '-f' for start_url and I don't know how to change it. Any direction would be appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This script is supposed to be runned in a terminal, not in a notebook.
So if you want to run it in a terminal, type the following :

```
python name_of_the_script.py your_first_argument_here
```

If you want to run it in a notebook, replace :

```
start_url = sys.argv[1]
```

by

```
start_url = your_first_argument_here
```

Of course your_first_argument_here shoud be a valid url.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! I tried running it in terminal and it returned with a "permission denied" I tried to run it in the notebook and it didn't show any errors it just ran and gave no output. I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Comment: In the notebook, did you put commas around the url to make it a string ? Have you checked for new files in your directory as the script is supposed to generate it ?

Comment: sorry, I intended to say quotes around url, not commas, like "this/is/my/url"

Comment: No worries, yes I did put quotes.